# Importing external type definition from node_modules using tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wish to use a type definition (`Token`) from an external library (`meriyah`), installed to `node_modules`.

The type definition is available locally in the `node_modules/meriyah/dist/token.d.ts` path.

In the TypeScript config, I have added the type definition file under `include`, and made sure `exclude` is empty, following advice [from a similar Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12334).

However, when running `tsc`, I get errors (`src/index.ts:2:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Token'.` and `error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Token'. Did you mean 'token'?`).

How can I fix this so TypeScript finds the type definitions?

The following minimal files can be used to reproduce the error:

`src/index.ts`:

```
export default function hello(): string {
  const token: Token = Token.Type;
  return "hello";
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "node_modules/meriyah/dist/token.d.ts"],
  "exclude": []
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "meriyah": "^1.9.3",
    "tslib": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "latest",
    "ts-node": "latest",
    "tslint": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf lib && tsc"
  },
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts"
}
```